# Switching pin to output in NXP LPC24xx

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, lpc

Suppose our program has just started after Reset, so all FIODIRs are 0 and corresponding pins are inputs, and therefore they are in the third state (right?).
And suppose I want instaneously switch some pin to output with 1. Then probably I'll write this:

```
FIOxDIR_bit.Px_xx = 1;
FI0xSET_bit.Px_xx = 1;
```

But what will be state of the pin **between** these two commands? Presumably output with 0.
Another option to perform such switching is:

```
FI0xSET_bit.Px_xx = 1;
FIOxDIR_bit.Px_xx = 1;
```

But the datascheet claims:

> If any pin is configured as an input or a secondary function, writing 1 to the corresponding bit in the IOSET has no effect.

Probably the same is true about *FIOSET* as well.
And that's exactly what we do in our latter code snippet. Though in my expierence this approach works well, but I'd like to have some theoretical basis for this.

Comment: It should be stated in the datasheet how long latency the GPIO pin has been you change data direction. On some MCUs you need to add a couple of dummy cycles (asm NOP or similar) between writing to data direction and the port register, in case you want to be certain that it is now in a defined state.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks, but the question is not about latency.

Comment: what did you see when you looked at this on the scope?

Comment: @old_timer, honestly I haven't look at this on the scope. Anyway, the scope would show only emperical data, for my specific MCU and circuit.

Comment: exactly the answer is specific to the chip design not generic, there is no possible generic answer for all mcus and circuits.  it would show you if the signal goes from floating to ground to high.

Comment: @old_timer, so you assume that second approach isn't robust?

Comment: I have looked on the scope however. The first approach really gives short time with zero output state of the pin.